# GNU Parallel --sshlogin remote shells

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I have a small test setup of 5-10 embedded devices, and would like to remotely run commands on them with GNU Parallel. But the commands I supply produce no output.

Copying and pasting the command output by `parallel -vv ...` into the `zsh` login shell on the device shows that the command executed by `parallel` are syntactically erroneous to `zsh`, and nre not run.

Changing the login shell would require rebuilding all the embedded images, because the devices have read-only filesystems.

Is there a way to work around this, possibly by:

- teaching my version of GNU Parallel (`GNU parallel 20130922` from Ubuntu  14.04 LTS) about zsh
- getting GNU Parallel to `exec /bin/dash`, which is also available, before running its command sequence
- or installing an upgraded version of GNU Parallel?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect from us here. If the commands are erroneous, fix them, no? We can't do that for you without seeing them. A common pitfall is shell escaping, but that'd need a command line as well. I don't think `parallel` cares what shell you have remotely (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Local commands defaults to the shell from which they are started. Remote defaults to $SHELL on the remote system. To override set $PARALLEL_SHELL (available since 20141022).

Comment: Thanks Ole! I think that would work if the destination system were a bit more fully featured, but the current Perl bootstrapping program won't run on the remote system because it doesn't have Perl :(.

Comment: ^ The Perl bootstrap script was observed with parallel `20150822`, obtained from ftp.gnu.org. I can see the script change based on my $PARALLEL_SHELL settings as you described, so that would fix the issue if the remote had Perl.

I imagine Parallel doesn't aim to support remotes without Perl installed? In any event, I really appreciate you having taken a look at my issue.

Comment: Without further information I cannot help further. Change your question to include a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ole, I was basically admitting defeat. I don't think GNU Parallel is really supposed to work with remote systems too small to have Perl installed at all? If it is supposed to work, I can come up with an example but it might take a bit of time to make it work over the Internet.